# does R cache results that are not assigned

Tags: r, statistics

Post code sample and data. My question is in the below sample. If I have a variable `x`, and I compute `table(x)`, is it possible to refer to the pre-computed `table(x)` later without assigning it to a variable?

```
x = c('a', 'a', 'b')
table(x)
```

Comment: What would you want to refer to it as, if you haven't assigned it to a variable? You can always refer to it as `table(df$c2)`. If your issue is with `<-`, you can also use `=` or `assign` for assignment. But unless you store it in a variable it will be lost and need to be recomputed if you want to use it again.

Comment: Also, why not just `dput()` your data to share it after transforming. All these extra steps, reading csv, changing names, converting columns, loading `ggplot2`, seem to have nothing to do with your question.

Comment: @Gregor, vote up. :) For "recomputed", you mean if I refer to `table(df$c2)` again, it will be recomputed? No cache, correct? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Gregor, vote up. I often see people write code like this, table something without assign to a variable, what is the purpose of such kinds of code?

Comment: @Gregor, vote up, and for your comments, "share it after transforming", which line in my code do you mean "transforming"? Thanks.

Comment: Probably they want to see the results as they print to the console. More advanced R users will not save such code in scripts.

Comment: @Gregor, thanks and it seems only for debug purpose. Vote up. If you could add a reply, I will mark it as answer to benefit future people search. :)

Comment: Starting in your `code` block, I would call lines 3, 4, 5 and 8 transforming, line 1 unnecessary because your question has nothing to do with `ggplot`, and `summary` lines also seem unrelated. Within the context of this question, it's not clear at all why this particular data matters at all. Why are you bothering sharing particular data when `x = c("a", "a", "b")` would illustrate the problem just as well?

Comment: @Gregor, vote up, why do you say `x = c("a", "a", "b")` illustrate the problem just as well? More details?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109091/discussion-between-gregor-and-lin-ma).

Comment: @Gregor, vote up and change title. Yes, I want to check if we could refer something in R without assign to a named variable. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, R does not cache results that are not assigned. It's not clear *how* you would want to refer to something later without giving it a name.

If you have intervening code between two calls of `table(x)`, `x` might have changed, the definition of `table` might have changed, either of which would require re-computation.

Furthermore, R doesn't know whether or not `table` is deterministic. Maybe `table` depends on random number draws, or on the time of day, or other variables. All of these possibilities make caching everything unreasonable. If *the user* knows that one computation can be re-used later, then the user can easily store the first result in an object (assigning it), and reference that object later.

Comment: Thanks for the help Gregor, mark your reply as answer. :)

Comment: @LinMa I also hope you see how much clearer your question is now after edits.